# Socketio giving Bad Request on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, socket.io

I deployed my application on heroku for testing. I am building a chat application with socketio and mongodb. It works fine until socketio does not start to work. When io starts, it shows application error/ Bad request/ No App Found. I tried many ways but they did not work for me.

Here is my code of Procfile and requirements.txt.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

requirements.txt

```
altgraph==0.17
bandwidth-sdk==10.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bidict==0.21.2
bot-studio==1.1.9
CacheControl==0.12.6
capture-the-flag==0.0.4
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.0.1
colorama==0.4.4
decorator==4.4.2
dnspython==2.1.0
docopt==0.6.2
enum34==1.1.10
eventlet==0.17.4
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.0
future==0.18.2
geocoder==1.38.1
google==3.0.0
greenlet==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
Js2Py==0.71
jsonpickle==0.9.6
keyboard==0.13.5
lxml==4.6.3
macholib==1.14
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
MouseInfo==0.1.3
msgpack==1.0.2
num2words==0.5.10
numpy==1.21.0
packaging==20.9
Pillow==8.2.0
pipwin==0.5.1
plivo==4.18.1
PyAutoGUI==0.9.52
pygame==2.0.1
PyGetWindow==0.0.9
pyglet==1.5.18
pyinstaller==4.3
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2021.2
pyjsparser==2.7.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymongo==3.12.0
PyMsgBox==1.0.9
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyperclip==1.8.2
PyPrind==2.11.3
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.27
pySmartDL==1.3.4
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.4
python-dotenv==0.18.0
python-engineio==4.2.0
python-socketio==5.3.0
pyttsx3==2.90
PyTweening==1.0.3
pytz==2021.1
pywhatkit==5.0
ratelim==0.1.6
requests==2.25.1
rotate-screen==0.1.0
rubicon-objc==0.4.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
tqdm==4.61.2
twilio==6.62.0
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.26.5
Werkzeug==2.0.1
wikipedia==1.4.0
youtube-video-play-pause-bot==1.0.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Comment: Please update your question with your code and the error traceback.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.